# Pyspark tabulate nulls, blanks, and other suspicious values

Tags: pyspark

For all of the columns in a Spark data frame, I need to tabulate the numbers of various values. Here's what I tried:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def get_counts(sdf, suspicious_values=("none", "null", "nan", "na", "n/a")):
    
    suspicious_values = list(suspicious_values)
    dict_is_null = {
        acol: sdf.filter(F.col(acol).isNull()).count() for acol in sdf.columns
    }
    dict_not_null = {
        acol: sdf.filter(F.col(acol).isNotNull()).count() for acol in sdf.columns
    }
    dict_is_blank = {
        acol: sdf.filter(sdf[acol].isin([""])).count() for acol in sdf.columns
    }
    dict_n_unique = {
        acol: sdf.groupBy(acol).count().count() for acol in sdf.columns
    }
    dict_is_suspicious = {
        acol: sdf.filter(F.lower(F.col(acol)).isin(suspicious_values)).count()
        for acol in sdf.columns
    }
    ddd = [
        dict_is_null,
        dict_not_null,
        dict_is_blank,
        dict_n_unique,
        dict_is_suspicious,
    ]
    labelz = [
        "null_count",
        "not_null_count",
        "blank_count",
        "unique_values",
        "is_suspicious",
    ]
    df_counts = pd.concat(
        [
            pd.DataFrame.from_dict(i, orient="index", columns=[j])
            for i, j in zip(ddd, labelz)
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    df_counts.index.name = "column_name"
    return df_counts
```

When the data has lots of rows (10 million+) and 200 columns, this takes a very long time.  I'm looking at the Spark activity and I see I'm causing it to launch a separate calculation for each variable for each summary number.

How to make it go faster?

Can these calculations be pressed into 1 request so that a column would only need to be loaded one time?

I'm trying to find example code in pyspark itself, but the `summary` function's work is shipped to the `_jvm` side so I cannot understand how they do that.

Comment: Not sure if it can help but [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ce5ddad990373636e94071e7cef2f31021add07b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/stat/StatFunctions.scala#L182) is the Scala code for `summary`.

Comment: Thanks, that does help.  I'm not a Scala expert, but looks like they have the same inefficient-looking "2 for loops" thing that I have.  But maybe they have it written in a way that Spark can optimize better.